# Lock Pages in Memory for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is a recommendataion regarding turning on Lock Pages in Memory for 64 bit SQL Servers.

Is there any implication on turning on lock pages in memory setting?

Comment: Just a note: For 64bit systems you will need Enterprise edition to use the Lock pages feature.

Comment: @StanleyJohns not true, there is a trace flag for Standard Edition as well, it just won't do it by default. For the OP please read http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/great-sql-server-debates-lock-pages-in-memory/, http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/sql-server-and-the-lock-pages-in-memory-right-in-windows-server/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/04/24/sql-server-locked-pages-and-standard-sku.aspx

Comment: @Aron Bertrand. The blog post from SQL Server MVP Glenn Berry I found my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recoomends as an option if you are experiencing buffer pool paging (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918483).